# NSMutableString thread safety?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a large NSMutableString (potentially hundreds of megabytes) and need to perform a lot of rangeOfCharacterFromSet: operations on it.

To improve performance I would like to have an NSOperationQueue split the string into ~100kb chunks and asynchronously process each one.

But because the string is so large, making immutable copies for each thread is not viable.

Assuming I do not allow the string to be modified (I intend to block the main thread until the operation queue is finished), is this safe?

Apple documents NSString as thread safe and all immutable object as "generally" not thread safe but presumably it only applies to some methods? rangeOfCharacterFromSet is the only one I'm using.

This code will run on both OS X an iOS (typically with smaller strings on iOS)

Comment: Why would each thread have separate "copies" of the original NSString? If the string is not allowed to be modified, why use a NSMutableString anyway?

Comment: Why would you block the main thread? If you're going to do that, what's the purpose of threading at all?

Comment: I have one more question: have you actually *tested* performance, or are you just guessing? Do you *know* there is a performance problem that requires splitting the string up?

Comment: matt: presumably Abhi is after concurrency, not asynchrony, in this case

Comment: Could this be a job for `dispatch_apply`?

Comment: Sure, though that doesn't change the question at all

Comment: @user2246674 this particular operation doesn't need to modify the string but other ones do.

Comment: @matt yes I have tested it, rangeOfCharacteFromSet is close to 100% of my CPU time, all I'm doing is finding all the instances of a particular character, and recording their position. I have to block the main thread because of how NSDocument works and I'm cocoa is already beach-balling reading a large file off the hard drive so why not add a little bit longer? I'm just trying to make it block for less time, not avoid blocking altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I suspect NSMutableString (or at least common implementations thereof) is safe for this, the safest answer is probably to create a single immutable copy, then do all the operations against that.

My caution is because very large NSMutableStrings may be implemented as a tree internally, and if that tree does lazy rebalancing on reads, there could be a thread safety issue.

Comment: I want my app to be able to open files as large as possible (even if that might mean the user has to wait several seconds for the file to open initially), creating a copy would double my app's memory consumption so I really want to avoid it. I'd have to do something more complex, such as make an immutable copy of the first 50MB of data, process that concurrently, then make an immutable copy of the next 50MB... ugh.

Comment: This is getting into "hacky relying on implementation details" stuff, but if you're not willing to rely on "it's probably fine" (which I totally understand), then you could do something like one -rangeOfString: serially to try to trigger any possible lazy state changes, then the rest concurrently.

Comment: Do you *need* to have the file loaded into memory all at once? Why not consider `mmap` or something?

Comment: @dreamlax mmap would give me a read-only copy of the file. I need a readwrite copy without writing anything to the disk until the user chooses to do so. And for some of the things I'm having performance issues even when it's in RAM, so storing it on the disk will not work at all.